# Expo Web Payments by extending React functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, payment

I have an Expo Web application deployed. I want to add a payments API, but expo Web payments is limited. I wanted to try adding a modal that processes the payments.

I know you can expand React.js functionality using Portals. Can portals (or something else) be used with Expo Web to create a modal that processes payments? This is an issue with expanding the functionality of the Expo Web library.

Thanks!